# WCF and nullable attributes in the generated schemas

Tags: wcf

I am trying to do some contract first development, and have already designed a schema where an element has `minoccurs=0` and `nullable=false`.
However I am not able to make a *DataContract* or *XmlSerializer* that generates this **xsd**.

I have an idea that this is not possible.

The only solution I have found is an ugly one, see it [here](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/content/DesignServiceContracts/DesignServiceContracts.html).

In this solution i have to implement the *IXmlSerializable* and do the shema and the serialization myself. So I would have to maintin both the schema and the C# class -> Ugly

Has anyone found a solution to this or heard from Microsoft that this is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, both `XmlSerialiser` and `DataContractSerializer` will generate object that will respect the schema if the object is filled correctly, but if the required values are not filled, the produced xml will not validate agains the schema.

You could try to use [XsdObjectGenerator](http://www.windevpowertools.com/tools/106).